# Function call with a callback inside submit event - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, stripe-payments, jquery-events

So what I am trying to do is to call a function with a callback inside a submit event. What happens is that callback functions finishes after the submit event, and I want it to be vice versa.

```
stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {;
    var $form = $('#new-card-details-form');
    if (response.error) {
        addErrorMessage(response.error.message);
        return false;
    } else {
        var token = response.id;
        $form.append($('<input id="token" type="hidden" name="token">').val(token));
      }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#new-card-details-form *').removeAttr('name');
   Stripe.setPublishableKey('key');
   var $form = $('#new-card-details-form');

   $(document).on('submit', '#new-card-details-form', function(e) {
       if (!$('#token').val()) {
           Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
           if (!$('#token').val()) {
               e.preventDefault();
           }
       }
   });
});
```

So what happens here is that form submits on second click, because on the first click when I check for token existance it doesn't yet exist because the stripeResponseHandler function will complete after the submit event. Is there a way in which I can make it work with the first click? I've tried submitting the form in the stripeResponseHandler with unbind() but that didn't work too.

Comment: remove this condition `if (!$('#token').val()) {` and do your thing when you append the token. or simply use the `stripeResponseHandler` for your conditions

Comment: I tried calling `$form.unbind('submit').submit()` in `stripeResponseHandler` but it didn't work.

Comment: unbinding is not the solution. if you think of it,as from what i understand from your code. it flows like this, on submit; get a token base from the form values; then set that token to the form, and submit.